# Import error aftert adding site.py file to project

Tags: python, importerror

After I've added `site.py` to top directory of my project, my application started to fail with an exception: `"ImportError: No module named 'bs4'"`.

Before adding this file, application worked file. `BeautifulSoup4` package is installed in used interpreter.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site.py` shadows built-in [`site`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) module.

Due to wrong `site.py` module being imported, paths used to search for user-installed packages are never set, therefore interpreter is unable to find `bs4` module.