# Python/PyCharm: sys.path "lib" not the same capitalization as venv's "Lib"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

1. I cloned a Python 2 project and used PyCharm to create a Python 2.7.12 virtualenv.
2. I am now getting an "ImportError" when I try to run the code.
3. While debugging I noticed that if I start the virtualenv and run the version of Python it contains, and then check the Path that is checked for modules, the "lib" is not capitalized (see second red arrow below).
4. However, in my venv folder, "Lib" *is* capitalized.

Is this OK?

[image]

---

Below is a screenshot of the traceback I'm getting. The first module imported is always not being found. If I start an interactive session using the venv I'm able to import all of the modules.  Even more strangely, if I create a *new* file and try to run it with just an import in it (say, 'test.py'), the traceback shows an error in the *original* file (site.py).

[image]

---

I pulled `site.py` into a new project and it seems that it is the actual name of the file as `site` that is causing the error:

Doesn't work:

[image]

Does work:

[image]

Comment: can you show us your traceback for the import error? I don't think the capital "L" is a problem here, as you can see your python/venv finds und uses the lib folder like normal. Its probably just PyCharm displaying it wrong.

Comment: @Sativa Thanks for your help. I've included an image of the traceback as well as some additional information about the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Ahh, there is a site.py within python. It is used to append search paths for third party packages to sys.path. Maybe it's conflicting

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is "Yes, it's OK".

The reason for the `ImportError` was that there was a top-level file named `site`.  As you can learn in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125919/import-error-aftert-adding-site-py-file-to-project), having a file named `site.py` confuses Python's package-finding tools, since there's a built in `site` module.